# SQL Server join two tables together add null if one table has more

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables joined. Table 1 would be the old products and table2 would be the new products. When I run this, I does give me a 1 to 1.

My problem is that table 1 has more "USB Drives" than, table 2 (and visa versa).

If table1 has more. How can I get to where it will show table1 and if table2 doesn't have a match. Just add a Null value.

Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT 
    table1.productid, table1.product, table1.catogory, 
    table2.productid, table2.product, table2.catogory
FROM 
    table1
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         table1.productid, table1.product, table1.catogory
     FROM 
         table1 
     WHERE 
         table1.productid = 12345 
         AND table1.product = 'USB Drive') AS table2 ON table1.product = table2.product 
                                                     AND table1.productid = table2.productid
WHERE 
    table1.productid = 12345 
    AND table1.product = 'USB Drive'
```

Comment: hi have you tried full outer join it will give you rows from both table an null which doesnot exist in table 1 and then you can filter which are not i.e tabl1.productidis not null ?

Comment: you you can share  table schema and sample data then I can try to right . if my approach suits you

Comment: Perhaps the following link will help you: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Yashveer Singh. Thanks!!! I actually forgot about the full outer join. No you didn't post as an answer. Do so, I removed my answer so you can add yours. Thanks again